# 9C and A2 errors when booting computer

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I recently installed Ubuntu on my machine and it's working more or less fine except for one really strange caveat. My machine will not boot unless the USB used to install Ubuntu is plugged in. It will give error codes A2 and 9C and then proceed to restart and try again. Having said that, it proceeds to boot into either windows or ubuntu from my hard drive via grub just fine if the USB key is plugged in. Is there any reason this might be the case? It's not the end of the world, but it's really annoying.

Specs:

Motherboard: MSI Z97S Krait Edition

Graphics Card: GTX 970

Processor: intel i7-4790k

OS: Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your partition layout of both disks. You should edit your question instead of replying with a comment.

Comment: What does the motherboard manual say causes those A2 and 9C errors? Please click [edit] and post the answer into your question. Questions should contain all the facts needed to solve the problem; Comments are a one way channel from us to you.